# Using QR codes for my smart contract

Tags: solidity, qrcode

I'm thinking of a service that unconditionally gives out ERC20 based tokens once a user scans a specific QR code that I have created (It may be a random passphrase, address etc...)
Is there a way to make this process automatic on my solidity contract?

Answer (score 1):

Well a smart contract can't obviously scan a QR code so you'll need some external code as well, no matter what.

As I see it, all the processing has to be done outside blockchain. So your out-of-chain program scans the code, processes it and then calls blockchain to distribute tokens.

A random passphrase directly into a smart contract won't work as there are no secrets in smart contracts. You'd have to hardcode the list of passphrases into the contract and at that stage everyone could see the passphrases and just execute all of them to get all the tokens.

A scheme based on addresses has actually better chances of succeeding but I can't see how it could work either. Even if the address was an address pointing to a 'secret' contract which would give out the tokens to anyone who calls it, people could find the contract without the address quite easily (direct searches to blockchain, check contract creation transactions from the same owner, seeing who owns tokens in the token contract etc)